# No detailed error messages

Tags: php

I am getting `internal server error` when calling php script via ajax. I set `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` but still no details .. what else should I do

Comment: Check your server's error logs

Comment: @j08691 error log is empty

Answer (score 0):

inside your php.ini the

display_errors = On

The php.ini file is where base settings for all php on your server, however these can easilybe overridden and alterd any place in the PHP code and affect everything following that change. This happens a in frameworks. A good check is to add the display_errors to you php.ini. If you don't see an error, but one is being logged, insert this at the top of the file causing the error:

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
If this works then something earlier in your code is disabling error display.